# "expected type-specifier" while trying to make .o from templated class

Tags: c++, templates, object-files

While compiling this with just an include, i get no errors whatsoever.

```
template <class T,
  class C = std::vector<T>,
  class S = std::less<typename C::value_type>,
  class H = std::less<typename C::value_type> > class MyHeap {
```

But when trying to make a .o from this class file, g++ says that "class C = std::vector," is expecting a type-specifier.

What is the reason for this?
I am a noob at templates so i can't really tell.

Comment: Show your testcase, including compilation commands.

Comment: That is not a class. It is a *class template*. You can't compile it into an object file.

Comment: Did you include the vector header? `#include <vector>`.

Comment: Yes i included the vector header. No i can't post the make command.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You should be able to, since it's valid C++ source code, as long as the right header files are included.  Of course, the resulting object file will be rather empty (or nearly so).

Comment: It actually does make sense not to be able to compile the code since templated classes are not the final code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compile templated classes to .o
Thanks to juanchopanza for the answer.